# Bizarre performance issue: Common Table Expressions in inline User-Defined Function

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, user-defined-functions, common-table-expression

Here's a brain-twister for the SQL guys - can anyone think of a reason why the first of these functions performs fine, and the second one runs dog-slow?

**Function A - Typically finishes in ~5 ms**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GoodFunction
(
    @IDs UniqueIntTable READONLY
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
    SELECT p.ID, p.Node, p.Name, p.Level
    FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT a.Ancestor AS Node
        FROM Hierarchy h
        CROSS APPLY dbo.GetAncestors(h.Node.GetAncestor(1)) a
        WHERE h.ID IN (SELECT Value FROM @IDs)
    ) np
    INNER JOIN Hierarchy p
    ON p.Node = np.Node
```

**Function B - Runs extremely slow - I gave up after 5 minutes**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.BadFunction
(
    @IDs UniqueIntTable READONLY
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
    WITH Ancestors_CTE AS
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT a.Ancestor AS Node
        FROM Hierarchy c
        CROSS APPLY dbo.GetAncestors(c.Node.GetAncestor(1)) a
        WHERE c.ID IN (SELECT Value FROM @IDs)
    )
    SELECT p.ID, p.Node, p.Name, p.Level
    FROM Ancestors_CTE ac
    INNER JOIN Hierarchy p
    ON p.Node = ac.Node
```

I'll explain below what this function does, but before I get into that, I want to point out that I don't think it's important, because as far as I can tell, **these two functions are exactly the same!**  The only difference is that one uses a CTE and one uses a subquery; the contents of the subquery in A and the CTE in B are *identical*.

In case anyone decides this matters: The purpose of this function is just to pick out all the possible ancestors (parent, grandparent, etc.) of an arbitrary number of locations in a hierarchy.  The `Node` column is a `hierarchyid`, and `dbo.GetAncestors` is a CLR function that simply walks up the path, it does not do *any* data access.

`UniqueIntTable` is what it implies - it's a user-defined table type with one column, `Value int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY`.  Everything here that should be indexed is indexed - the execution plan of function A is essentially just two index seeks and a hash match, as it should be with function B.

Some even stranger aspects to this strange problem:

- I'm not even able to get an estimated execution plan for a simple query using function B.  It almost looks like the performance issue has something to do with the *compilation* of this simple-looking function.
- If I take the "body" out of function B and just stick it into an inline query, it runs normally, same performance as function A.  So it only seems to be a problem with a CTE *inside a UDF*, or conversely, only with a UDF that uses a CTE.
- The CPU usage on one core on the test machine spikes all the way up to 100% when I try to run B.  There doesn't seem to be much I/O.

I want to just shrug it off as a SQL Server bug and use version A, but I always try to keep Rule #1 (*"SELECT Ain't Broken"*) in mind, and I'm concerned that the good results from function A are somehow a localized fluke, that it will "fail" the same way that B does on a different server.

Any ideas?

---

**UPDATE** - I'm now including a complete self-contained script to reproduce.

**GetAncestors Function**

```
[SqlFunction(FillRowMethodName = "FillAncestor", 
    TableDefinition = "Ancestor hierarchyid", IsDeterministic = true,
    IsPrecise = true, DataAccess = DataAccessKind.None)]
public static IEnumerable GetAncestors(SqlHierarchyId h)
{
    while (!h.IsNull)
    {
        yield return h;
        h = h.GetAncestor(1);
    }
}
```

**Schema Creation**

```
BEGIN TRAN

CREATE TABLE Hierarchy
(
    ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1)
        CONSTRAINT PK_Hierarchy PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    Node hierarchyid NOT NULL,
    [Level] as Node.GetLevel(),
    Name varchar(50) NOT NULL
)

CREATE INDEX IX_Hierarchy_Node
ON Hierarchy (Node)
INCLUDE (Name)

CREATE INDEX IX_Hierarchy_NodeBF
ON Hierarchy ([Level], Node)

GO

INSERT Hierarchy (Node, Name)
    SELECT CAST('/1/' AS hierarchyid), 'Alice' UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST('/1/1/' AS hierarchyid), 'Bob' UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST('/1/1/1/' AS hierarchyid), 'Charles' UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST('/1/1/2/' AS hierarchyid), 'Dave' UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST('/1/1/3/' AS hierarchyid), 'Ellen' UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST('/1/2/' AS hierarchyid), 'Fred' UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST('/1/3/' AS hierarchyid), 'Graham' UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST('/1/3/1/' AS hierarchyid), 'Harold' UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST('/1/3/2/' AS hierarchyid), 'Isabelle' UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST('/1/4/' AS hierarchyid), 'John' UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST('/2/' AS hierarchyid), 'Karen' UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST('/2/1/' AS hierarchyid), 'Liam' UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST('/2/2/' AS hierarchyid), 'Mary' UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST('/2/2/1/' AS hierarchyid), 'Nigel' UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST('/2/2/2/' AS hierarchyid), 'Oliver' UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST('/2/3/' AS hierarchyid), 'Peter' UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST('/2/3/1/' AS hierarchyid), 'Quinn'

GO

CREATE TYPE UniqueIntTable AS TABLE 
(
    Value int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Value)
)

GO

COMMIT

GO
```

The above code/script can be used to create the CLR function/DB schema; use the same `GoodFunction` and `BadFunction` scripts in the original.

Comment: My mistake. I didn't notice that you were using SQL 2008 at first. Comment withdrawn :)

Comment: It would really help if you could also provide a script to create tables and populate with some data so we can do some testing

Comment: BTW- Any reason why you're using Node.GetAncestor in the first example and ObjectNode.GetAncestor in the second? Or was that just a typo?

Comment: When you say you're "not even able to get an estimated execution plan" for function B, what happens when you try to get one in SQL Server Management Studio?  While you're waiting for it to generate, can you go to another window and do an exec dbo.sp_who2, and run the query on this page: http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Misc_DMV_queries Report back what the wait type is for the waiting query, and it'll show what's holding up the execution plan.

Comment: @Brent Ozar: I can run `sp_who2` and the query on your page.  The former is not too helpful - the status is `RUNNABLE`, and the command starts with `EXECUTE` and then changes to `INSERT` after about a minute (although it still shows as `EXECUTE` in the Activity Monitor... weird).  The query you linked to, unfortunately, does not even show a result for the test process ID - the only row returned is the one for the DMV query itself.  Looks like this trail is running cold...

Comment: Aha!  So I'm betting something is wrong with the way SQL Server is creating that execution plan.  Have you tried doing this same exact thing on a separate server, like a dev server, and from another workstation?  It could also be an issue with the patch levels on either one.

Comment: @Brent Ozar: Indeed, it almost seems like the optimizer is getting into an infinite loop or something of the sort, which is very strange because it's not that complicated a query (or is it?).  There's no other server I can test on at the moment - the schema itself is brand-spankin' new - but it should be getting deployed into testing next week so maybe I'll have more information then.

Comment: I'm not so familiar with CTE stuff but have a naive guess. Any chance that the CROSS APPLY causes a recursive call to CTE that has no base step to cancel recursion?

Comment: @Ekin Koc: Neither the `GetAncestors` function nor the CTE are recursive, so that *shouldn't* be the case.  Interesting thought though, maybe the optimizer *thinks* that something in there is recursive and is trying to generate a recursive query plan when it shouldn't be.

Comment: If you aren't getting an estimated execution plan, then the optimizer is almost certainly failing.  That would make this a bug/limitation/"feature" of the algebrizer/optimizer.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: But *why* is it failing?  I guess I need to ask Microsoft.  Maybe `SELECT` really is broken?

Comment: @Aaronaught:  Again: a *bug* in the SQL-Server optimizer causes it to fail.  The T-SQL compiler catches and suppresses the consequent error and just goes with the default, un-optimized query plan.  Slowness ensues.  The default query plan is the plan produced by the compiler when it translates the SQL Code syntax directly into Logical/Physical operators (it is both order and syntax sensitive).  Normally the compiler then calls the optimizer/algebrizer to elaborate valid transforms of the default query plan and then return the lowest cost variant found within a time limit.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: That doesn't jibe with the actual results, though - if the optimizer is really just failing and the compiler is catching it then I would still end up with an estimated plan - just a bad one.  I'm not getting any plan at all, and even the most inefficient query imaginable would still return almost instantly with a test table of only 15 rows.  So I'm not ready to believe the "optimizer silently failing" explanation; there's something else, like an infinite loop, and when I ask *why*, I mean *what exactly could be triggering this 'bug'?

Comment: In any event, I guess one definite answer is emerging, which is that the only definite answer is going to come from the SQL Server team at Microsoft.  It'll be interesting to see what they have to say.

Comment: @Aaronaught: No that is not correct.  Please re-read my last comment, you are confusing two different things.  The optimize is called with a parse tree and a time-limit.  When successful, it either returns *before* the time-limit with 1) an "optimal" re-ordered(and/or transformed) parse tree and 2) costing, etc. for each node in the transformed parse tree, or else it returns *at* the time-limit with thesame two things, but instead of "optimal", its just the best that it found before running out of time.  (1) and (2) together form and "execution plan".  This is *NOT* what you are getting ...

Comment: (cont.) Rather, instead of * succeeding* (whether it hits the time limit or not), in your CTE case I am saying that the optimizer is ***failing*** (which is a bug) and returns *nothing* to the compiler.  In this case the compiler has to fall-back to the original bound parse-tree which is still executable, but usually very bad.  *Much* worse than a non-optimal results from a "lazy" optimizer, plus it is dependent on the syntax elements and even their order.  **This** is why 1) it's so slow, 2) its different than another query that is *logically* identical, and 3) you get *no* query plan.

Comment: The key points here are 1) the optimizer running out of time is *not* a failure or a bug, it still returns something to the compiler.  and, 2) *Only* the optimizer can produce cost estimates, without that you do not have a Query Plan, just a parse tree.  If you do not get a query plan, it is because of a failure in the optimizer.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: I understand what you're trying to say but this happens on the **estimated** execution plan, so it's never actually *running* the query at all, and even if it was, the characteristics would be senseless.  Hours to run a 15-row query, bricking the CPU for the entire duration?  I don't think so.  There is **no** chance that even the "default query plan" - a term that **you** introduced, not me - is causing those effects when executed.

Comment: OK, who downvoted the question?  Seriously!?  How much more clear and specific can a question be?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Haha, try this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('_HappyFunction' ) IS NOT NULL DROP FUNCTION _HappyFunction
IF OBJECT_ID('_SadFunction'   ) IS NOT NULL DROP FUNCTION _SadFunction
IF TYPE_ID  ('_UniqueIntTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TYPE _UniqueIntTable
GO

CREATE TYPE _UniqueIntTable AS TABLE (Value int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)
GO

CREATE FUNCTION _HappyFunction (@IDs _UniqueIntTable READONLY)
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN
  SELECT Value FROM @IDs
GO

CREATE FUNCTION _SadFunction (@IDs _UniqueIntTable READONLY)
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN 
  WITH CTE AS (SELECT Value FROM @IDs)
  SELECT Value FROM CTE
GO

-- this will return an empty record set
DECLARE @IDs _UniqueIntTable 
SELECT * FROM _HappyFunction(@IDs)
GO

-- this will hang
DECLARE @IDs _UniqueIntTable 
SELECT * FROM _SadFunction(@IDs)
GO
```

Who would have guessed?

Comment: That's crazy!  What in the world is going on here?

Comment: It's officially on MS Connect now: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=527843.  I'm marking this answer as the accepted one because it eliminated several variables from the equation (`hierarchyid`, `CROSS APPLY`, and the schema in general), it simplified the repro steps and made the case that much easier to submit.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

I've reproduced the behavior on SQL 2008 SP1, substituting a SQL UDF for the CLF UDF dbo.GetAncestors. I tried both a table valued function and an in-line function; neither one made a difference.

I don't know what is going on yet, but the benefit of others, I'll include my definitions below.

```
-- try a recursive inline UDF...
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetAncestors(@hierarchyid hierarchyid)
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN (
WITH recurse AS (
    SELECT @hierarchyid AS Ancestor
    WHERE @hierarchyid IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Ancestor.GetAncestor(1) FROM recurse
    WHERE Ancestor.GetAncestor(1) IS NOT NULL
    )
SELECT * FROM recurse
)

-- ...or a table-valued UDF, it makes no difference
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetAncestors(@hierarchyid hierarchyid)
RETURNS @return TABLE (Ancestor hierarchyid) 
AS BEGIN
    WHILE @hierarchyid IS NOT NULL BEGIN
        INSERT @return (Ancestor)
        VALUES (@hierarchyid)
        SET @hierarchyid = @hierarchyid.GetAncestor(1)
    END             
    RETURN
END
```

Choose one of the definitions above, and then run this to watch it hang:

```
DECLARE @IDs UniqueIntTable 
INSERT @IDs SELECT ID FROM Hierarchy
RAISERROR('we have inserted %i rows.',-1,-1,@@ROWCOUNT) WITH NOWAIT
SELECT * FROM dbo.GoodFunction(@IDs) a
RAISERROR('we have returned %i rows.',-1,-1,@@ROWCOUNT) WITH NOWAIT
GO

DECLARE @IDs UniqueIntTable 
INSERT @IDs SELECT ID FROM Hierarchy
RAISERROR('we have inserted %i rows.',-1,-1,@@ROWCOUNT) WITH NOWAIT
SELECT * FROM dbo.BadFunction(@IDs) a
RAISERROR('we have returned %i rows.',-1,-1,@@ROWCOUNT) WITH NOWAIT
GO
```

The second batch never even *starts*. It gets past the parse stage but appears to get lost somewhere between bind and optimize.

The bodies of both functions compile to exactly the same execution plan, outside the function wrapper:

```
SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT ON
GO
DECLARE @IDs UniqueIntTable 
INSERT @IDs SELECT ID FROM Hierarchy
SELECT p.ID, p.Node, p.Name, p.[Level]
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT a.Ancestor AS Node
    FROM Hierarchy c 
    CROSS APPLY dbo.GetAncestors_IF(c.Node.GetAncestor(1)) a
    WHERE c.ID IN (SELECT Value FROM @IDs)
) np
INNER JOIN Hierarchy p
ON p.Node = np.Node

;WITH Ancestors_CTE AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT a.Ancestor AS Node
    FROM Hierarchy c
    CROSS APPLY dbo.GetAncestors_IF(c.Node.GetAncestor(1)) a
    WHERE c.ID IN (SELECT Value FROM @IDs)
)
SELECT p.ID, p.Node, p.Name, p.[Level]
FROM Ancestors_CTE ac
INNER JOIN Hierarchy p
ON p.Node = ac.Node


-- both return this:

    |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([p].[Node]))
         |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([p].[Level]=[Scratch].[dbo].[Hierarchy].[Level] as [p].[Level]))
         |    |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([p].[Level]=[Scratch].[dbo].[Hierarchy].[Node] as [p].[Node].GetLevel()))
         |         |--Index Scan(OBJECT:([Scratch].[dbo].[Hierarchy].[IX_Hierarchy_Node] AS [p]))
         |--Top(TOP EXPRESSION:((1)))
              |--Filter(WHERE:([Recr1005]=[Scratch].[dbo].[Hierarchy].[Node] as [p].[Node]))
                   |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([c].[Node]))
                        |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([Value]))
                        |    |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:(@IDs))
                        |    |--Clustered Index Seek(OBJECT:([Scratch].[dbo].[Hierarchy].[PK_Hierarchy] AS [c]), SEEK:([c].[ID]=[Value]) ORDERED FORWARD)
                        |--Index Spool(WITH STACK)
                             |--Concatenation
                                  |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1011]=(0)))
                                  |    |--Constant Scan(VALUES:(([Scratch].[dbo].[Hierarchy].[Node] as [c].[Node].GetAncestor((1)))))
                                  |--Assert(WHERE:(CASE WHEN [Expr1013]>(100) THEN (0) ELSE NULL END))
                                       |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([Expr1013], [Recr1003]))
                                            |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1013]=[Expr1012]+(1)))
                                            |    |--Table Spool(WITH STACK)
                                            |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1004]=[Recr1003].GetAncestor((1))))
                                                 |--Filter(WHERE:(STARTUP EXPR([Recr1003].GetAncestor((1)) IS NOT NULL)))
                                                      |--Constant Scan
```

Very interesting. Submit a bug report at Microsoft Connect, have them tell you what's going on.

Comment: Interesting that it's reproducible without the CLR function, that will make it a lot easier to submit a bug report if it comes to that.  Thanks for having the patience to get your hands dirty with this one and confirming that it is not just a case of the optimizer simply giving up.

Answer (score 1):

This is a guess and just a guess, but perhaps it has something to do w/ how the optimizer makes a pretty good guess at the best execution plan, but does not make an exhaustive search for one.

So, query execution works like this:

parse -> bind -> optimize -> execute

The parse trees for your two queries will certainly be different. The bind trees are *probably* different. I don't know enough about the bind phase to state that conclusively, but assuming the bind trees *are* different, then it may require a different number of transforms to get the A and B bind trees to the same execution plan.

If it takes two additional transforms to get query B to the ~5ms plan, the optimizer may say "good enough" before discovering it. Whereas for query A, the ~5ms plan maybe just inside the search cost threshold.

Comment: I think that this is about as good an answer as anyone but MS can give.  If it fails in optimize, it can still execute because the parse tree produced by the bind phase *is* executable.  But 1) performance is awful, because it is unoptimized, 2) it is syntax and order sensitive, because it is the optimizer that takes care of that, and 3) there *is* *no* *true* *query* *plan*, because QPs include costing and the optimizer does that too.  Note that all three of these symptoms are evident in the OPs question.

Comment: As I've now mentioned in some of the question comments, it can't simply be an inefficient plan being chosen because the estimated plan never comes back at all, and the issue is reproducible on a very small table where even a triple-cartesian-product would take less than a second.  As much as I wish it did, the "lazy optimizer" explanation does not seem to hold water.

Comment: It is not an inefficient plan being choosen.  It is *NO* plan being choosen and the original parse-tree has to be used.  (see my comments to your question, above)

Answer (score 0):

In the first statement, your join is

```
np INNER JOIN Hierarchy p
    ON p.Node = np.Node
```

your second statement is

```
Ancestors_CTE a
INNER JOIN Hierarchy p
ON p.Node = a.Node
```

However, a is also used as an alias for dbo.GetAncestors(c.Node.GetAncestor(1)) in the CT. Try exchanging `Ancestors_CTE a` with e.g. `Ancestor_CTE acte`, to ensure the optimizer isn't confused with the double use of a as an alias.

That said, I'm not sure how good SQL server is at appliying the correct indexes when creating a CTE. I've had problems with this before, and used table variables instead with great success.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not it - SQL Server has no problems working it out, but good eye, I've updated the question to make this explicit.

Answer (score -1):

As I understand it when using CTEs in batch you must end the statement with a ";". It has something to do with the interpretation of the WITH clause. Try this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('_HappyFunction' ) IS NOT NULL DROP FUNCTION _HappyFunction  
IF OBJECT_ID('_NowHappyFunction') IS NOT NULL DROP FUNCTION _NowHappyFunction  
IF TYPE_ID  ('_UniqueIntTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TYPE _UniqueIntTable  
GO  

CREATE TYPE _UniqueIntTable AS TABLE (Value int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)  
GO  

CREATE FUNCTION _HappyFunction (@IDs _UniqueIntTable READONLY)  
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN  
  SELECT Value FROM @IDs  
GO  

CREATE FUNCTION _NowHappyFunction (@IDs _UniqueIntTable READONLY)  
RETURNS @Table TABLE
(
Value INT
)
BEGIN
  ;WITH CTE AS (SELECT Value FROM @IDs)
  INSERT INTO @Table
  SELECT Value FROM CTE
  RETURN
END
GO

-- this will return an empty record set  
DECLARE @IDs _UniqueIntTable   
SELECT * FROM _HappyFunction(@IDs)  
GO  

-- this will no longer hang and will also return an empty record set 
DECLARE @IDs _UniqueIntTable   
SELECT * FROM _NowHappyFunction(@IDs)  
GO
```

Comment: That won't execute.  The ; in front of the WITH statement will cause an error preventing you from creating the function.

Comment: Corrected the syntax and changed the inline function to a multiline statement function. Compiles now.