# Is this a dumb way to sort a few values?

Tags: t-sql, sorting

I'm checking dimensions on things and I want to know the 3 dimensions from largest to smallest.

So here's the kinda' whizzy function I wrote:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SortDimensions
    ( @aDim1 udt_Dimension
    , @aDim2 udt_Dimension
    , @aDim3 udt_Dimension 
    )
RETURNS @rDimensions TABLE 
    ( Dim1 udt_Dimension
    , Dim2 udt_Dimension
    , Dim3 udt_Dimension 
    )
AS
BEGIN
  ; WITH OrderedDims ( Dimension ) AS ( 
                SELECT @aDim1
      UNION ALL SELECT @aDim2
      UNION ALL SELECT @aDim3
   )
  ,      Pairs ( Name, Value ) AS ( 
      SELECT 'Dim' + CAST( ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY( Dimension ) DESC ) AS varchar ), Dimension 
        FROM OrderedDims 
  )
  INSERT INTO @rDimensions ( Dim1, Dim2, Dim3 )
      SELECT MAX(Dim1), MAX(Dim2), MAX(Dim3) 
        FROM Pairs 
      PIVOT ( MAX(Value) FOR Name IN ( [Dim1], [Dim2], [Dim3] )) p

  RETURN
END
```

Isn't this a lot of work for doing the same thing as this:

```
DECLARE @lDim1 udt_Dimension
DECLARE @lDim2 udt_Dimension 
DECLARE @lDim2 udt_Dimension

IF @aDim2 > @aDim1 
  BEGIN
    SELECT @lDim1 = @aDim2 
         , @lDim2 = @aDim1
  END
ELSE 
  BEGIN 
    SELECT @lDim1 = @aDim1 
         , @lDim2 = @aDim2
  END

IF NOT @aDim3 > @aDim2 
  BEGIN 
    SET @lDim3 = @aDim3
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
    SET @lDim3 = @lDim2
    IF @aDim3 > @lDim1 
      BEGIN
        SET @lDim2 = @lDim1
        SET @lDim1 = @aDim3
      END
    ELSE 
      BEGIN
        SET @lDim2 = @aDim3
      END
  END 

INSERT INTO @rDimensions VALUES ( @lDim1, @lDim2, @lDim3 )
```

I believe a DBA once told me that the guys who designed SQL server reused the the technology of temp tables for variables, so its pretty much a wash between tables and variables. (Go ahead and disabuse me of this notion, if it's not true.)

Comment: And yes, #temp tables and @table variables are almost identical in their implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that this should be faster:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SortDimensions
    ( @aDim1 udt_Dimension
    , @aDim2 udt_Dimension
    , @aDim3 udt_Dimension 
    ) RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
(
    WITH cte As (     SELECT @aDim1 As Dim
            UNION All SELECT @aDim2
            UNION ALL SELECT @aDim3
    )
    , cte2 As ( SELECT Dim, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Dim) As Odr FROM cte )
    SELECT  
            MAX(CASE WHEN Odr=1 THEN Dim ELSE NULL END) As Dim1,
            MAX(CASE WHEN Odr=2 THEN Dim ELSE NULL END) As Dim2,
            MAX(CASE WHEN Odr=3 THEN Dim ELSE NULL END) As Dim3
    FROM    cte2
)
```

Comment: It is also cleaner. Does the pivot slow it down? See I get confused, because the thing that I have always loved about SQL is the set-based "arithmetic" focus, so I fell in with the Anti-RBAR crowd pretty easily, but some of those guys don't like CASE statements. Also, I like inline TVFs, but I've read that CTEs can really throw the optimizer off.

Comment: Recursive CTE's might throw the optimizer off, but normal CTE's are just aliased subqueries and should work exactly the same.  If you've heard differently, please point me to it because I'd really like to know about it.  And as Jeff Moden can attest, I'm as Anti-RBAR as anyone, and `CASE` expressions used as a Cross-Tab/poor-man's Pivot is straight out of the Anti-RBAR handbook.  AFAIK, `CASE` expressions are only a problem when they're used as On/Off switches in the WHERE clause (which is the Catch-All Query problem).

Comment: perhaps this is out of date, but I found it googling stuff: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086946/bizarre-performance-issue-common-table-expressions-in-inline-user-defined-funct#2151909

Comment: @Axeman That's a known bug that was fixed in a CU for SQL 2008 years ago: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/527843/deadlock-hang-cpu-thrashing-when-combining-udf-cte-and-udtt.  No reason to avoid CTEs.